# How do I pass a dynamic filename to ng-include

Tags: javascript, angularjs, refactoring

On a project I'm working on, I'm implementing some SVG maps.  The app I'm working on has a number of locations that have two SVG documents corresponding to it: a visual map that details what an area looks like, and a 'spaces' map that has polygons that are assigned UI Bootstrap tooltip events, so that you can read information about the space.  For example:

```
<h3 class="text-center">Fargo Building 1</h3>

<div class="svg-map" ng-include="'Content/svg/fargo-map.svg'"></div>
<div class="svg-overlay" ng-include="'Content/svg/fargo-map-spaces.svg'"></div>
```

However, all of my maps are all doing *that exact same thing, every time - no exceptions.*  Using routing, I set up a system whereby I can pass information about a map to my `mapController`, and attempted to refactor said markup this way:

*Note: the filenames are being passed with the single-quotes already in them.*

```
<h3 class="text-center">{{ vm.mapInfo.mapName }}</h3>

<div class="svg-map" ng-include="{{ vm.mapInfo.mapFile }}"></div>
<div class="svg-overlay" ng-include="{{ vm.mapInfo.mapSpaces }}"></div>
```

One slight problem: the refactor as above throws the following Angular exceptions:

```
Syntax Error: Token '{' invalid key at column 2 of the expression [{{ vm.mapInfo.mapFile }}] starting at [{ vm.mapInfo.mapFile }}].
Syntax Error: Token '{' invalid key at column 2 of the expression [{{ vm.mapInfo.mapSpaces }}] starting at [{ vm.mapInfo.mapSpaces }}].
```

Following the instructions (removing the second layer of curly braces) yielded a different error.  Removing the curly braces period resulted in HTTP 404 errors.

**Question:** In what way can I programmatically pass a filename for `ng-inclu`sion?

*Note: I'm not concerned about being able to change the `ng-inclu`ded page at runtime, either.  When the user navigates to a different map, the routing system takes care of everything.  I just want to be able to include a file from a `controllerAs` variable.*

Comment: Just use the expression, i.e. `ng-include="vm.mapInfo.mapFile"` etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work without the curly brackets:

```
<div class="svg-map" ng-include="vm.mapInfo.mapFile"></div>
```

In your controller:

```
var vm = this;
vm.mapInfo = { mapFile: "Content/svg/fargo-map.svg"};
```

See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hmd6kjz5/) for a similar solution.

Comment: Another aspect of your fix, is I had to remove the single-quotes in the path that was being passed into the controller.  But, it works!  Thanks.